# Laravel: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/DateRangeFilterIterator.php on line 47

Tags: performance, laravel

I am getting the following error on my Laravel project on nearly every page:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/DateRangeFilterIterator.php on line 47
```

This happens especially when our server traffic is load is high. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 9):

As it turns out, we were using the disk filesystem for our sessions. The disk I/O rate of the session files was the bottleneck. Changing the session driver to redis or database fixed it.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Has been working fine for years and then all of a sudden this started happening. Switched to database and solved the issues!

Comment: Bro you rescue my money to resize my server. I got 100% CPU usage because of this and more than 2 days looking for the problem with found nothing. Now my server runs about 5% CPU usage. Thank you

Comment: I've spent days agonizing over 100% cpu spikes and dropped connections, all the while losing customers. This answer saved the day.

Comment: changing to database driver look like it helps.